# Batch file to boot into grub2

Tags: linux, windows-10, bootloader, grub2

I want to make a desktop shortcut on windows 10 to boot directly into grub2

using a batch file or any other way

how do I do that

Comment: Grub2 expects to execute after a system reset, which will put the system in a quiescent state.  You cannot *"boot directly into grub2"* other than perform a restart from Windows.

Comment: Taking hints from : https://askubuntu.com/questions/635205/link-to-restart-from-windows-to-ubuntu and with few modifications